# Images wont show up since I updated wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, upgrade

Yesterday I updated Wordpress to the new 4.4.2 version. After the upgrade, no images will show up on my blog. Previous to the upgrade everything was working perfectly. Here's what I've done so far:
 - Deactivated all plugins to see if one was the problem - didn't fix
 - Cleared all cache - didn't work
 - Logged out of wordpress & logged back in - didn't work
 - Tried uploading a new image & adding it to the page code - didn't work
 - There are no updates needed in any theme, plugin, or wordpress

Here are some things to consider:
 - When I go to the page & mouse over an image, the mouse recognizes that there's an image there.
 - When I go directly to the image url - I can see it fine.
 - When I switch to another theme - I can see images fine.

My url is: http://www.medicalbillingstudycourse.com
The theme is: Evident

I gather it must be something in the code of the theme? 
I would love some help with this one!!!

Pearl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like one of your `js` files aremissing. the `.main img`class has `opacity` set to `0` which the js is probably fading in.

either find that file or change your css to opacity 1

Comment: Are you saying that a file could have been deleted during the wordpress upgrade?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again - but what file should I look in to try to change the opacity?

Comment: [http://www.medicalbillingstudycourse.com/wp-content/themes/Evident/css/basic-layout.css?ver=4.4.2](http://www.medicalbillingstudycourse.com/wp-content/themes/Evident/css/basic-layout.css?ver=4.4.2) on line 73